# Water rushing out to meet wave term

Tags: waves, terminology

Is there a word for the phenomenon of water seeming to rush out to meet an oncoming wave? Perhaps it's more of a physics terminology question?

Comment: I think backwash might be the right term - though maybe that doesn't address the visual perception of the water 'rushing' to meet the wave

Comment: what you are asking here has many different names like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_current and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertow_(water_waves)

Comment: I'm looking for a term like `convection` that describes this type of motion, if that helps